# Can you get the response data from Volley outside of the stringRequest variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I want to get the Volley stringRequest response from my website outside of the variable.

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = ""


// Request a string response from the provided URL.
val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    Response.Listener<String> { response -> 
        var obj = JSONObject(response) <-- cant access this variable outside of stringRequest
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { textView3.text = "That didn't work!" })

stringRequest.body.toString() <-- cant covert null to string

stringRequest.headers.toString() <-- output is {}

//here i want to do something like 

if (response == "True") {
    //do something
}
```

On the website that I'm accessing there is nothing more than `{"check":"True"}`

Comment: Its actually asynchronous behavior, since the `StringRequest isn't blocking`, you cannot verify the call has succeed or has been done in the next line.

Comment: Why can't you take your if call to the response listener?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu because my entire project is going to depend on pieces of code like that, and its nice to be able to access that data from outside the response listener. But you are saying I can't do it any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation is asynchronous in the way its built in, What you actually can do to look it more like synchronous is if you use coroutines in your project, You can use `suspendCoroutine`, see
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html

**Example:**

```
suspend fun getData(url: String) = suspendCoroutine<String?> { cont ->
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            cont.resume(response)
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { cont.resume(null) })

    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

Now you can access the response string out of Response.Listener()

**Edit:** Additionally you can do `cont.resumeWithException(e)` instead if you dont want to return nullable expression and check nullability every time you use this function.

Comment: now you can call `.body` or `.headers` or check on the return value of the getData() it will return `Response`

Comment: @Tiebe Groosman check this if you like to call those things outside of the listeners/variables.

Comment: Thanks! I have one problem. On your line with `suspendCoroutine<Response>` I get an error on `Response` `One type argument expected for class Response<T : Any!>`

Comment: @TiebeGroosman ah sorry fixed it, i didn't tested it so it happened, it will be same as you receiving in the Listener.

Comment: Sorry to disturb again, but now getting an error on `cont.resume(response` and `cont.resume(it)` with the error being `Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in inline fun <T> Continuation<T>.resume(value: T): Unit`

Comment: @TiebeGroosman check now, i actually wasn't awared that error listener does not give any object in lambda. If the function returns null then error has occured and if Response<String> call succeed and you can do what you want